# Linux shell - Calculate sha1 hash for each executable currently running

Tags: shell

I would like to calculate the sha1 hash of each executable file that is currently running on my Linux machine and display the result (hash path/file).
Can anyone please help me with a shell script?

Thank you, 
dk

Comment: Don't take offence but it's xy quostion, check: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I recommend you to have a look at ps and whereis commands